# Typing a GraphQL query with mandatory variable with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

Is there a way with TypeScript (or any other tool) to throw an error at compile/build time if I'm using a GraphQL query without passing a required variable?

For instance, I have this GraphQL query:

```
query booksByAuthor($author: String!) {
  books(author: $author) {
    title
    year
  }
}
```

these TS types:

```
interface Book {
  title: string;
  year: number;
}

interface BooksByAuthorType {
  books: [Book];
}

interface BooksByAuthorVariables {
  author: string;
}
```

and this React component (fetching data with `@apollo/react-hooks`):

```
const Books = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery<
    BooksByAuthorType,
    BooksByAuthorVariables
  >(query); // notice I'm not passing `author` here

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.books.map(
        book => <li>{`${book.name} (${book.year})`}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

How do I use TypeScript (or any other tool) in order to have an error in this case?

Comment: Since the `options` parameter is optional, as you pointed out, I don't imagine there's a way to do that without wrapping the hook with your own hook that uses stricter typing for both `options` and its `variables` parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for something that could infer that check from the actual query. But this probably resides more on the hook side than on GraphQL/TS themselves. Maybe with a static analysis tool (besides TS)? I'll update my question.

Comment: Maybe you can create a function which accept the query parameter(author). Do thw typechecking there and then pass it to query function.